# Add multiple fields to Java 5 HashSet at once?

Tags: java

Is there a better way to do this so I don't have to have 50 ".add()"s in there? Like a comma separated list or something (like JavaScript arrays).

```
private static final Set<String> validStates = new HashSet<String>();

validStates.add("AL");
validStates.add("AK");
validStates.add("AZ");
validStates.add("AR");
validStates.add("CA");
validStates.add("CO");
validStates.add("CT");
validStates.add("DE");
validStates.add("DC");
validStates.add("FL");
validStates.add("GA");
validStates.add("HI");
validStates.add("ID");
validStates.add("IL");
validStates.add("IN");
validStates.add("IA");
validStates.add("KS");
validStates.add("KY");
validStates.add("LA");
validStates.add("ME");
validStates.add("MD");
validStates.add("MA");
validStates.add("MI");
validStates.add("MN");
validStates.add("MS");
validStates.add("MO");
validStates.add("MT");
validStates.add("NE");
validStates.add("NV");
validStates.add("NH");
validStates.add("NJ");
validStates.add("NM");
validStates.add("NY");
validStates.add("NC");
validStates.add("ND");
validStates.add("OH");
validStates.add("OK");
validStates.add("OR");
validStates.add("PA");
validStates.add("RI");
validStates.add("SC");
validStates.add("SD");
validStates.add("TN");
validStates.add("TX");
validStates.add("UT");
validStates.add("VT");
validStates.add("VA");
validStates.add("WA");
validStates.add("WV");
validStates.add("WI");
validStates.add("WY");
```

Something like:

```
validStates.add("AL", "AK", "...");
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`Set#of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E...)) for this.

```
validStates = Set.of("AL", "AK", "..");
```

In case you're not on Java 9 yet, then you could use [`Stream#of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of(T...)) instead.

```
validStates = Stream.of("AK", "AL", "..").collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

In case you're even not on Java 8 yet, then use the [`HashSet` constructor taking a `Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Collection)) in combination with [`Arrays#asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)).

```
validStates = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("AL", "AK", ".."));
```

It makes however more sense to have them in some [properties file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) or in a DB which you load by one or two lines of code so that you don't need to hardcode them all in Java.

Comment: validStates = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"AL", "AK", ".."}));

Comment: If this solution throws error for you then you have probably imported `edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.Arrays`

Answer (score 7):

If you fancy using the excellent [Google Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), you can use:

```
Set<String> validStates = Sets.newHashSet("AL", "AK", "...");
```

Answer (score 3):

You could have a static `String[]` with all the states, then iterate over the array:

```
String states[] = {"AL","AK","AZ","AR",...etc...};
for (String currState : states) {
   validStates.add(currState);
}
```

I don't remember if this "foreach" construct came in 1.5 or 1.6....

Answer (score 2):

```
HashSet<String> hs = Sets.newHashSet("abc","xyz");
```